# ANSI SQL: Ordering results by picking some certain values of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, ansi-sql

I'm catching up on ANSI SQL, and got stuck with a theoretically easy question that I can't figure out myself. I hope someone can give me a hand.

How can i do to order results of a query by some certain values of a column?

I just need a hand to figure how to include the "place it at the bottom" clausule with chemistry and physics, due i can not include a logical expression in the ORDER BY clausule.

Thanks.

..................

table nobel ( winner, yr, subject)

Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list chemistry and physics last.

https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial#Chemistry_and_Physics_last

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr = 1984 ORDER BY <......>, subject, winner;
```

Comment: You can use a case expression to put specified values before/after others. ANSI SQL compliant since many years.

Comment: For what it's worth, that sqlzoo thing contains links to youtube videos with the solutions to its problems.

Comment: That my first thougt, include a IN clause on the oORDER BY criteria, but is didnt work. The solution show in the video below give by the page is not working in his own page. When i try it, it give me back a sintax error near the keywor IN..

Comment: ANS SQL allows an IN in the ORDER BY. Which dbms is used?

Comment: Im not sure, Im not working on my own BBDD. It suposed to be pure SQL, but the page has it embedded, Aniway, if all the opinions points that this is the rigth way, probalby is a bug on this particular exercise.

Comment: A very few DBMS:es are fully ANSI SQL compliant. The one you're using here isn't. You can verify _syntax_ here https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/